# What's Meruem's nen type?

Tags: hunter-x-hunter

So far in anime, I haven't seen any technique that shows what's his nen type.
I read the chimera arc years ago so I'm not sure, but I "think" I remember in a moment Meruem growing a pair of wings. If my memory is right, I'm not sure if that could be a natural ability or something related with an enhancement nen skill.
Is there any technique that gives some hints about his nen type?

Comment: Mereum is a Specialist. He can inherit power the moment he consumes it or took a part of it(nen)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the story, Meruem's initial ability gives him strength through consumption. His aura grows every time he devours a user of Nen, with their aura synthesizing to his own. This ability (Aura Synthesis) doesn't belong to any of the 5 basic categories, thus falls in the 6th category, making him a specialist. After absorbing large parts of Shaiapouf and Menthuthuyoupi, he was able to use their abilities too, making them his own. Further details about his new abilities can be found [here](https://hunterxhunter.fandom.com/wiki/Meruem#Nen).